# IDE Insight quit working

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

At some point, my IDE Insight function stopped working.  I have checked both the XE5 and XE6 versions that I have on my system and neither work, so it must be environmental.

When I click on the menu item, nothing pops up.  There is no error given, just no IDE Insert screen.  The same results happen when using the shortcut.

I am running Windows 7, Delphi Professional XE5 and XE6.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: +1 for running into the same trap as almost everyone with XE5 and XE6 because the edit in the toolbar is so subtle. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The IDE Insight window was removed in XE5. Instead, there's an edit box top right of the screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> gives it the focus) that you type into and get a dropdown list of commands to pick from in response.

This is documented in [What's New in Delphi and C++Builder XE5](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE5#Changes_to_IDE_Insight_for_XE5).