# How to Restore original IDE Insight window?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

The IDE Insight window was removed in XE5 and replaced by a search box in the upper right corner.

Is there an IDE option to restore the original IDE Insight 
Window?

Comment: I feel your pain. I'm very happy remaining on XE3!

Comment: The more I use XE+, the more I like D7.  In my more fanciful moments, I think EMBA should get out of the IDE business and leave it to 3rd parties like MMX's.  That way, the OTA might get a bit more attention.

Comment: You should also see [IDE Insight quit working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23143898), which shows exactly when it was removed and where that is documented (in XE5).

Comment: @KenWhite, I've seen that prior to posting. If you read first line of my question I say that I know it was removed and when. But the word removed is ambigious, I figured it's worth asking if there is any way to get that back, officially or unofficially.

Comment: The word "removed" has a specific meaning. :-) It says "removed", and was specifically documented as being "removed". I simply provided the link trying to be helpful so you could see where it was documented. Sorry for trying to help.

Comment: @KenWhite, Why did you construe my comment as offensive? Anyway, in the documentation it says that the Insight Window was ***replaced***, not removed. Even if it would say removed, it doesn't mean that it was removed entirely from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an IDE option to disable this abomination and restore the original IDE Insight Window?

No there is not.

Comment: Well that sucks. Not even through some IDE hacking?

Comment: Maybe you could hack it. No idea. Is the dialog even present in the executable any more? I doubt it.

Comment: @PeterVonča, I second that. The very first thing to examine is the presence/absence of IDE Insight form amongst the resources.

Comment: ... it is `TIDEINSIGHTFORM` and should reside or not in `coreide`